# How to change the file name while downloading from minio?

Tags: storage, minio

I am using min.io server for storing the objects. with the hash value as a name and their respective extension but, while downloading files from min.io I want to give them back their original name.

I have read the documentation but i couldn't find the correct answer.

I tried Content-Deposition header but for min.io we get the download URL with the object key and then redirect to the download URL which is generated by min.io server.

Any help would be appreciated and if you need more details please comment and ask i will update.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Content-Deposition' header must be used in the response header. If you use the `getPresignedObjectUrl` method in the mini Java SDK and set 'Content-Deposition' header in GET URL, it will not work at all. I encountered this problem too, and my Solution is getting object in Spring Boot and resend this object by attaching the header 'Content-Deposition'. Or send common get URL without  'Content-Deposition' header and save data in the blob

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const fileUrl = 'http://192.168.30.102:9000/library/book/file/MRXZNy1vw1qHX5bl/26170462-1672-457b-b413-e85b7a287d8c';

axios.get(fileUrl, {
  responseType: 'blob',
}).then(response => {

  const filename = 'downloaded-file.txt';

  const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });

  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  link.download = filename;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();

  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}).catch(error => {
  console.error('Error:', error);
});
```